# Не пойму в чем проблема, работа с while()

Tags: c++

файл main.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"

using namespace sf;

int main() {

    bool isGame = true;
    bool isg = true;

    while (game.isOpen()) {
        while (isg) {
            while (isGame) {
                ...
                if (y > 500) {
                    isGame = false;
                    Menu(game, score);
                    break;
                }
                ...
            }
            isGame = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

файл menu.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _MENU_H
#define _MENU_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Time.h>

using namespace sf;

void Menu(RenderWindow& game,int score) {
    bool isMenu = true;

    while (isMenu) {
        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (menuNum == 1) {
                isMenu = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif _MENU_H
```

По-моей задумке, когда объект опускается ниже 500 единиц, вызывается функция void Menu(). Затем, если я хочу сыграть снова, в данном случае вот это условие 
`

```
if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (menuNum == 1) {
                isMenu = false;
            }
```

`
То я просто выхожу из цикла ф-ии void Menu() и возвращаюсь в первоначальный цикл. Но, при этом ничего не происходит, но по задумке --  затем выхожу из самого "глубокого" цикла в файле main, ставлю переменной true и обратно захожу в самый "глубокий" цикл. Извините если замучал этим текстом, мне кажется что ошибка лежит на поверхности, но я никак не могу до этого додуматься

Comment: Так а в чем проблема-то?

Comment: `if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (menuNum == 1) {
                isMenu = false;
            }` при этом ничего не происходит, моя вина, забыл добавить

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос, это кусок кода, который и так есть в вопросе. Вы написали, что хотите, чтобы код делал,  но не написали, что он на самом делает.

Comment: Ну, при нажатии ничего не происходит. На действие пользователя - моё приложение никак не реагирует

Comment: Ну если у вас выставлен isGame = false, то верните его в true при выходе из меню.

Comment: Я вроде-бы возвращаю, только в main'e

Comment: Хорошо, лучше создать новую тему, или изменить эту?

Comment: Да, лучше выложить более полный код, просто измените эту тему.

Comment: С вашего позволения немного подредактировал, убрав лишнее и оставив главное. А то было не совсем понятно, что за функции и как они между собой взаимодействуют.

Comment: Конечно, спасибо)

Comment: Скорее всего я что то не заметил, но мне кажется что значение y не меняется и цикл while 3 уровня всегда вызывает menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае нужно какое-либо совместно используемое хранилище, которое бы позволило получать значение как из одной функции, так и из другой. А так же какой-либо механизм переключения с одной функции на другую.

Хранить общие ресурсы можно в глобальных переменных, промежуточных классах или статических классах. Для примера можно взять последний, должно выглядеть как-то так:

`MySettings.cpp`

```
class MySettings
{
    private:
        static bool isGame;
    public:
        static bool getIsGame() { return isGame; }
        static void setIsGame(bool status) { isGame = status; } 
};
bool MySettings::isGame = true;
```

Дальше подключаем наш файл к `menu.h`. Теперь надо разобраться с тем, что между функциями надо переключаться. Для этого лучше поместить код из main в отдельную функцию и убрать прямой вызов Menu.

```
void RenderGame(){
    while (MySettings::getIsGame()) {
        ...
        if (y > 500) {
            MySettings::setIsGame(false);
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
}

int main() {
    while(game.isOpen()){
        if(MySettings::getIsGame()){
            renderGame();
        } else {
            Menu(game, score);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ну и меню поменять из этого же условия.

```
void Menu(RenderWindow& game,int score) {
    bool isMenu = true;

    while (isMenu) {
        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (menuNum == 1) {
                MySettings::setIsGame(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)